# Compile NDK code against in different compilers

Tags: android, android-ndk

I get the following error log when trying to do the NDK-build....I suspect that this is because I compile the code against wrong C++ compiler,now I am using GNU C++.. using the command

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Please let me know  how can I use a different version of the compiler and different compilers available.

```
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<Imf::Name const, Imf::Channel> >::operator++()':
/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `Imf::Pxr24Compressor::uncompress(char const*, int, Imath::Box<Imath::Vec2<int> >, char const*&)':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:431: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `tooMuchData':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:173: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:173: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<Imf::Name const, Imf::Channel> >::operator++()':
/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `Imf::Pxr24Compressor::compress(char const*, int, Imath::Box<Imath::Vec2<int> >, char const*&)':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:404: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:404: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `uiMult<unsigned int>':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `uiAdd<unsigned int>':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `uiMult<unsigned int>':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `uiAdd<unsigned int>':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN3Imf15Pxr24CompressorE[typeinfo for Imf::Pxr24Compressor]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o): In function `Imf::RleCompressor::uncompress(char const*, int, int, char const*&)':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfRleCompressor.cpp:283: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfRleCompressor.cpp:283: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o): In function `uiMult<unsigned int>':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN3Imf13RleCompressorE[typeinfo for Imf::RleCompressor]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `Imf::ZipCompressor::uncompress(char const*, int, int, char const*&)':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp:192: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp:192: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `Imf::ZipCompressor::compress(char const*, int, int, char const*&)':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp:159: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp:159: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `uiMult<unsigned int>':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `uiAdd<unsigned int>':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `uiMult<unsigned int>':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `uiAdd<unsigned int>':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN3Imf13ZipCompressorE[typeinfo for Imf::ZipCompressor]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(IlmThread.o): In function `IlmThread::Thread::start()':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:74: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:74: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(IlmThread.o): In function `~Thread':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:67: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:67: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:67: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:67: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(IlmThread.o): In function `Thread':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:61: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:61: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:61: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:61: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(IlmThread.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN9IlmThread6ThreadE[typeinfo for IlmThread::Thread]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(IlmThread.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN3Iex9NoImplExcE[typeinfo for Iex::NoImplExc]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(dcraw_common.o): In function `LibRaw::stretch()':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:9060: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:9060: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(dcraw_common.o): In function `LibRaw::fuji_rotate()':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:9015: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:9015: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(dcraw_common.o): In function `LibRaw::median_filter()':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:4429: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:4429: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(dcraw_common.o): In function `LibRaw::remove_zeroes()':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:337: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:337: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(dcraw_common.o): In function `LibRaw::recover_highlights()':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:4521: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:4521: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(dcraw_common.o): In function `LibRaw::blend_highlights()':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:4493: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:4493: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(dcraw_common.o): In function `LibRaw::scale_colors()':
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:3789: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/home/flock/Desktop/FreeImage/jni/../Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:3789: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
./obj/local/x86/libFreeImage.a(dcraw_common.o): In function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

-fexceptions to the LOCAL_CXXFLAGS in your Android.mk file

I also have this in my Application.mk file

APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := all

I think I was getting those same errors before adding the -fexceptions

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the wrong compiler, this is a bug in gcc/NDK that manifests itself slightly differently on Linux, Cygwin, and Windows (non Cygwin).

Here's what I did to fix it (works for Linux and for one of my developers who is blind and has to use Cygwin)...

- Remove the line that says, `APP_STL := gnustl_static` from your Application.mk (it's broken in the NDK, and it's broken slightly differently on Linux Cygwin, Windows)
- add a line to $(LOCAL_LDLIBS) in your Android.mk file that says,

`$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a`

also add two lines to Andriod.mk that say,
`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include`
`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include`

The forgoing will accomplish what having, "APP_STL := gnustl_static" in your Application.mk was supposed to.